# Ionic/Angular translation of a boolean string

Tags: angular, ionic2

I would like to translate following string:

```
{{order.shipped?'Shipped':'No Shipped'}}
```

So what I did is I added | translate:

```
{{order.shipped?'Shipped':'No Shipped' | translate}}
```

In the json language file I tried to translate the whole string so:

```
 "order.shipped?'Shipped':'No Shipped'":"order.shipped?'geschlossen':'offen'"
```

But also only the part with 'Shipped':'No Shipped'. However, both alternatives are not working. So I tried to translate both strings seperately:

{{order.shipped?'{{'Shipped' | translate}}':'No Shipped'}}

I tried also alternatives with ' or " or enclosed like '".
Do you know how I can translate this whole string?

Comment: Well to improve readability I'd recommend you to place this logic in a typescript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a function?

```
orderFunc(order){
  return order.shipped?'Shipped':'No Shipped';
}
...
{{orderFunc(order) | translate}}
```